# MuPAD - complicated solve() solutions

Tags: matlab, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

I am trying to solve an equation for one variable as shown in the picture:

[image: solving]

Judging from the output of the second command, I should be able to get an expression for $\ddot{\theta}$.

I tried several options for `solve`, but I still get the same long result. I only want it to move the other terms to the right hand side and divide.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the "long result" returned by [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/solve.html) It's giving you helpful information. Certain combinations of parameter values will result in special results. You should also be able to extract the first case from the solution if you like. Importantly, it looks like you've not told MuPAD anything about your [assumptions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/when-to-use-assumptions.html) for the parameters and variables. Read about those [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/properties-and-assumptions.html).